# Extending Django Admin tabular.html custom checkbox action

Tags: python, django

I have two table Defendant and Defendant_Potential

```
class Defendant(models.Model):
    fullname         = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False,)
    fname            = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = u'First Name', blank = True, null = True,)
    midname          = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = u'Middle Name', blank = True, null = True,)
    lname            = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = u'Last Name', null = True, blank = True,)
    marked           = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = u'Check box mark', null = True, blank = True,)
class Defendant_Potential(models.Model):
    defendant    = models.ForeignKey('Defendant', related_name = "Defendant_defendantID",)
    midname      = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True, default = None)
    address      = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False,)
    city         = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = False,)
    state        = models.CharField(max_length = 5, null = False,)
    zip      = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = False,)
```

And its Admin Models like :

```
class Defendant_Potential_Individual_Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Defendant_Potential

    formset = NoDeleteAdminInlineFormSet
    readonly_fields = ('midname', 'address')
    extra = 0
    template = "admin/cdradmin/defendant/edit_inline/tabular.html"

class DefendantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fullname', 'fname','midname','lname')

    inlines = [Defendant_Potential_Individual_Inline, ]
```

In the tabular.html i have a custom checkbox

```
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="defendant_potential_checked" data-defendant_id="{{ inline_admin_form.original.defendant_id }}" value="{{ inline_admin_form.original.id }}"></input></td>
```

My Qustion is Whenever the checkbox checked , then the 'Defendant' table get update the marked field (This should happen olny we click submit button on change_from.html.

I did some research on save_model,save_formset etc But i did not get the proper solution any one can help me to do this ??

Comment: If marked is a checkbox field than why not create it as a Boolean field? Boolean fields become checkboxes on a ModelForm. I guess hardcoding the checkbox field on the template is not the right way to do it.

Comment: marked field is in Defendant table. When the user check the check box . this field should get populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have to models:

```
class Hive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    marker = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Bee(models.Model):
    hive = models.ForeignKey(Hive)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then your admin could look like this:

```
class BeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    check = forms.BooleanField(label="check", required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Bee

class BeeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = BeeForm
    model = Bee

class HiveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BeeInline,)
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        for bee_form in formset:
            if bee_form.cleaned_data.get('check') == True:
                form.instance.marker = True
                form.instance.save()
        super(HiveAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)

admin.site.register(Hive, HiveAdmin)
```

Comment: This help me to fix my issue , Thank you @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1647273/christian-thieme